# whl file is not a supported wheel on this platform - how can i fix?

Tags: linux, pip, debian, raspbian, python-wheel

i am currently using raspberry pi desktop, running debian in my empty laptop.

I wanna use tensorflow lite interpreter from tensorflow official website.

I typed `$ python3 --version` and got `Python 3.7.3` ,
typed `$ uname -a` and got `Linux raspberry 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux`. this is my platform info.

and visited tensorflow lite interpreter website and downloaded compatible wheel file named
`https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`

i finally typed `$ pip3 install https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`

I cannot find any weird thing in my work, and i want your help to complete this job.

`$ pip install https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl` also does not work.

Comment: `pip --version` ? `pip3 --version` ?

Comment: up to date. maybe 20.3.4

Comment: pip --version : 21.1.3

Comment: pip3 --version : also 21.1.3

Comment: `pip --version` also says Python version; that's important but you skipped it.

Comment: It says python 3.7 ; full output is ```pip 21.1.3 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7) ```

Comment: `type -a python3` to verify it's `/home/pi/.local/bin/python3.7`; `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"` to check if it's 32 or 64-bit.

Comment: ```type -a python3``` gives ```python3 is /usr/bin/python3```, ```python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)``` gives ```32```. is it right? thanks for help again.

Comment: You have 32-bit Python but is trying to install 64-bit wheel. Either upgrade Python or download 32-bit wheel.